# In Matlab, what does the time scale [0 20] actually mean, when using an ODE solver?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

When I use to ode45 solver, and input the time scale as [0 20], and get my solutions, I print out the values for the time, t, and notice that they are something like this:

t =

```
     0
0.0000
0.0000
0.0000
0.0000
0.0000
0.0001
0.0001
0.0001
0.0003
0.0004
0.0005
0.0006
0.0013
0.0019
0.0026
0.0032
0.0055
0.0077
0.0099
0.0121
0.0147
0.0173
0.0199
0.0225
0.0255
0.0285
0.0315
0.0345
0.0379
0.0413
```

... until t = 20.

What does this mean?  Is it a 20-second simulation?

For my model, I coded up quantities to be in meters, seconds, kilograms, e.g. the gravitational acceleration is coded as g = 9.81.

I know that ode45 uses an adaptive time-step method, but I'm not sure how to interpret the time scale.

Comment: Yes, it is a 20 second simulation. Not in real world time though (a simulation might take an hour to range over $[0, 20]$), but computationally it will run through values of $t \in [0, 20]$ which _is supposed to represent_ time. An adaptive time step just means the simulation will take larger time steps when it doesn't have to resolve fine details and will take smaller time steps when it does.

Comment: ok thanks, @mattos